# Solve $(D^2 + 3D + 2)y = e^{e^x}$ using method of variation of parameters?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This question was asked in a test and I'm stuck while solving this using method of variation of parameters. Here's an screenshot of my solution,

[image]
[image]

While finding particular integral I was not able to solve integration of e^e^x?
Can anyone please help me out a bit here. I was not able to understand how to solve it further.

Comment: You just pulled a function out of integral as if it were a constant. That's a big no-no. Also you missed a minus sign in your Wronskian calculation, it should actually be $-e^{-3x}$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry W is e ^ -3x ... I wrote it wrong in the paper. Corrected it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, but note that $W(x)=e^{-3x}$
$$PI=-e^{-2x} \int e^{2x} e^{e^{x}} dx + e^{x} \int e^{x} e^{e^{x}} dx$$
Let $e^x =t \implies dx=\frac{dt}{t},$ then
$$PI=-e^{-2x} \int t e^{t} dt + e^{-x} \int e^{t} dt$$
$$PI=-e^{-2x}e^{t}(t-1)+ e^{-x} e^{t}= e^{-2x+e^{x}} .$$

Comment: I didn't get why dx = dt/t ?

Comment: $e^x=t\implies d(e^x)=dt\implies e^xdx=dt\implies tdx=dt$

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc Thank you. Also just one more doubt. when calculating integral of $e^-x * e^e^x .dx$ we will get integral of $e^-t * dt$ I mean negative sign will remain isn't it?

Comment: Yes now I have corrected $e^{-x}$ to $e^{x}$, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$(D^2 + 3D + 2)y = e^{e^x}$$
It's Euler-Cauchy's equation hidden. To simplify substitute $u=e^x$ then equation becomes:
$$(u^2D^2 + 4uD + 2)y = e^{u}$$
Try $y=x^m$
$$m^2+3m+2-0 \implies m=-1,-2$$ 
$$ \implies S_y=\{\frac 1 u, \frac 1 {u^2}\}$$
$$(D^2 + \frac 4uD + \frac 2 {u^2})y =\frac { e^{u}}{u^2}$$
The Wronskian is 
$|W|=  -\frac 1 {u^4}$
And the particular solution is:
$$y_p=\frac {e^u}{u^2}$$
Substitute back $u=e^x$

Answer (score 2):

Writing $y=z\exp(\exp x)$ reduces the equation to$$\color{red}{(4z+2z^\prime)\exp x}+\color{limegreen}{z^{\prime\prime}+3z^\prime+2z}+\color{blue}{z\exp 2x-1}=0.$$Each monochromatic expression is $0$ if $z=\exp-2x$.

Answer (score -1):

the final answer should be
$PI = e^{-2x} * e^{e^x}$

Comment: Put the mathematical expression between dolars.